# distinct maximal normal subgroups of different order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can two distinct maximal normal subgroups have different order? In the quaternion group there are 3 distinct maximal normal subgroups but they all have order 4. So, i want to know if there exist such subgroups in the realm of group theory

Comment: Any1 plz help me on this matter

Comment: If it helps, H is a maximal normal subgroup of G iff G/H is a simple group. So you're asking if some finite group G can have two normal subgroups A,B of different orders, where each of G/A and G/B are simple.

Comment: I know about that theorem but it doesnt say anything about having distinct normal subgroups of different order

Comment: See my (possibly really off-base) answer, which I'll delete if it isn't really what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $G=Z_2+Z_3$ (where $+$ means direct sum)? This group is abelian so all subgroups are normal. It also has the two subgroups $H=Z_2+\{0\}$ and $K=\{0\}+Z_3$ of orders $2,3$ respectively. Each of these is a maximal subgroup of $G,$ and so also a maximal normal subgroup of $G$ (all subgroups being normal).